# How to check particular object key is exist as a value of another object key?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Requirement:

I have to iterate multiple objects, it contains properties. so I have to iterate each object and check properties values(the key name is mapping) matching with the first object key.

for example:

```
Node1, Node2, Node3

JSON: 
 {
  "Node1": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "x": {
        "type": "string",
        "mapping": "",
        "checked": false,
        "defChecked": true
      },
      "y": {
        "type": "string",
        "mapping": "",
        "checked": false,
        "defChecked": true
      }
    },
    "defChecked": true
  },
  "Node2": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "body": {
        "type": "string",
        "mapping": "Node1.inputs.x",
        "checked": false,
        "defChecked": true
      },
      "subject": {
        "type": "string",
        "mapping": "",
        "checked": false,
        "defChecked": true
      },
      "toemail": {
        "type": "string",
        "mapping": "",
        "checked": false,
        "defChecked": true
      },
      "body_placeholders": {
        "type": "string",
        "mapping": "",
        "checked": true,
        "defChecked": true
      },
      "subject_placeholders": {
        "type": "string",
        "mapping": "",
        "checked": false,
        "defChecked": true
      }
    },
    "defChecked": true
  },
  "Node3": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "email": {
        "type": "text",
        "description": null,
        "default": null,
        "mapping": "Node2.inputs.toemail",
        "isSelected": true,
        "defChecked": true
      },
      "firstname": {
        "type": "text",
        "description": null,
        "default": null,
        "mapping": "",
        "isSelected": true,
        "defChecked": true
      },
      "lastname": {
        "type": "text",
        "description": null,
        "default": null,
        "mapping": "Node2.inputs.body_placeholders",
        "isSelected": true,
        "defChecked": true
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "uuid",
        "description": null,
        "default": null,
        "mapping": "",
        "isSelected": true,
        "defChecked": true
      }
    },
    "defChecked": true
  }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "Node1": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "y": {
        "type": "string",
        "mapping": "",
        "checked": false,
        "defChecked": true
      }
    },
    "defChecked": true
  },
  "Node2": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "subject": {
        "type": "string",
        "mapping": "",
        "checked": false,
        "defChecked": true
      },
     
      "subject_placeholders": {
        "type": "string",
        "mapping": "",
        "checked": false,
        "defChecked": true
      }
    },
    "defChecked": true
  },
  "Node3": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "firstname": {
        "type": "text",
        "description": null,
        "default": null,
        "mapping": "",
        "isSelected": true,
        "defChecked": true
      },
      
      "id": {
        "type": "uuid",
        "description": null,
        "default": null,
        "mapping": "",
        "isSelected": true,
        "defChecked": true
      }
    },
    "defChecked": true
  }
}
```

for the above JSON - Node1 has a property 'x's and this property mapped or not another object properties(Node2 and Node3). if you see the JSON it x mapped with Node2 like ( Node1.inputs.x)

if it's matches then i have to remove the object Node1.x from the json. similary for others

Comment: and where is your code ?

Comment: Kindly explain more

Comment: Show us the desidered output

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito - Output added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```js
let input = {
  "Node1": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "x": {
        "type": "string",
        "mapping": "",
        "checked": false,
        "defChecked": true
      },
      "y": {
        "type": "string",
        "mapping": "",
        "checked": false,
        "defChecked": true
      }
    },
    "defChecked": true
  },
  "Node2": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "body": {
        "type": "string",
        "mapping": "Node1.inputs.x",
        "checked": false,
        "defChecked": true
      },
      "subject": {
        "type": "string",
        "mapping": "",
        "checked": false,
        "defChecked": true
      },
      "toemail": {
        "type": "string",
        "mapping": "",
        "checked": false,
        "defChecked": true
      },
      "body_placeholders": {
        "type": "string",
        "mapping": "",
        "checked": true,
        "defChecked": true
      },
      "subject_placeholders": {
        "type": "string",
        "mapping": "",
        "checked": false,
        "defChecked": true
      }
    },
    "defChecked": true
  },
  "Node3": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "email": {
        "type": "text",
        "description": null,
        "default": null,
        "mapping": "Node2.inputs.toemail",
        "isSelected": true,
        "defChecked": true
      },
      "firstname": {
        "type": "text",
        "description": null,
        "default": null,
        "mapping": "",
        "isSelected": true,
        "defChecked": true
      },
      "lastname": {
        "type": "text",
        "description": null,
        "default": null,
        "mapping": "Node2.inputs.body_placeholders",
        "isSelected": true,
        "defChecked": true
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "uuid",
        "description": null,
        "default": null,
        "mapping": "",
        "isSelected": true,
        "defChecked": true
      }
    },
    "defChecked": true
  }
};

for (let i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
   Object.entries(input["Node" + (i + 1)].properties).forEach(prop => {
      if (prop[1].mapping.includes("Node" + i)) {
        let attrToCancel = prop[1].mapping.split('.')[prop[1].mapping.split('.').length -1];
     
        delete input["Node" + i].properties[attrToCancel];
        delete input["Node" + (i + 1)].properties[prop[0]];
      }
   });
}

console.log(input)
```

Get the `Object.entries` of input, then intercept the `mapping` property, read it and cancel the property on previous `Node`.

Comment: Thank you. let me check with my actual code

Comment: I have updated code like this but it's not working. code i shared

Comment: @bagya if the JSON is the same is impossible that is not working... Check better

Answer (score 1):

if you post your code we can help you more
but for now, if you want to replace values between that array you can make that there's a lot of ways but that depends on much of the data and the way to use it

```js
    const updateData = (YourData) => {

        for (const [MyNodeName, MyNodeValue] of Object.entries(YourData)) {
            if (MyNodeValue.properties) {
                for (const [propKey, propValue] of Object.entries(MyNodeValue.properties)) {
                    if (propValue.mapping && propValue.mapping !== "") {
                        var updateKeyArr = propValue.mapping.split(".inputs.");
                        console.log(updateKeyArr)
                        if (updateKeyArr.length > 0) {
                            if (YourData[updateKeyArr[0]] &&
                                YourData[updateKeyArr[0]].properties[updateKeyArr[1]]

                            ) {
                                YourData[MyNodeName].properties[propKey].mapping = YourData[updateKeyArr[0]].properties[updateKeyArr[1]];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return YourData;
    }
    console.log(updateData(data))
```